# Inline jQuery unexpected token switch

Tags: javascript, jquery

Stumped as to why this simple code keeps giving me a

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token switch

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        setInterval('switch()', 5000);
    });

    function switch(){
        var $active = $('#placeholder img.active');
        var $next = $active.next();

        $next.addClass('active');
        $active.removeClass('active');
    }
</script>
```

I thought functions can be outside the `document.ready` function? When I tried putting `switch()` inside the `.ready` function, it gave me the same error. My jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kL1Lrb2z/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message indicates, [switch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) is a keyword, and thus may not be used as a function name. To fix the issue, rename your function to something else, such as `mySwitch`.

Comment: Well that's embarrassing. Now I've got other errors but at least this one is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Switch` is actually a js function, try calling your function something else like `switchit` or something that isn't an existing function name.